# Context bound [T: Manifest] -> Nothing

Tags: scala

I use Jackson Scala Module.

I've created a little serialization tool which handle the json payloads received by Play2 framework.

```
  def unserializePayloadAs[T](implicit requestContext: RequestContext[JsValue]): T = {
    val json: String = Json.stringify(requestContext.request.body)
    unserialize(json)
  }

  def unserialize[T](json: String): T = {
    objectMapper.readValue(json)
  }
```

The readValue of Jackson Scala Module has the signature:

```
  def readValue[T: Manifest](content: String): T = {
    readValue(content, constructType[T])
  }
```

When trying to use my deserialization code, I have a stack.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate abstract type [simple type, class scala.runtime.Nothing$] (need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7bb78579; line: 1, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ThrowableDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(ThrowableDeserializer.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2041) ~[jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper$class.readValue(ScalaObjectMapper.scala:157) ~[jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at utils.CustomSerializer$$anon$1.readValue(CustomSerializer.scala:17) ~[na:na]
at utils.CustomSerializer$.unserialize(CustomSerializer.scala:39) ~[na:na]
at utils.CustomSerializer$.unserializePayloadAs(CustomSerializer.scala:35) ~[na:na]
```

As expected, it works fine when I add the manifest in my code:

```
  def unserializePayloadAs[T: Manifest](implicit requestContext: RequestContext[JsValue]): T = {
    val json: String = Json.stringify(requestContext.request.body)
    unserialize(json)
  }

  def unserialize[T: Manifest](json: String): T = {
    objectMapper.readValue(json)
  }
```

---

Can someone explain what happens there? 
When we call a method with a `Manifest` context bound, with a parametrized method with no `Manifest`, then the Manifest of `Nothing` is provided to the first method?

I would have expected some kind of compilation error, telling me I'm calling the `readValue` with a parametrized type that has no `Manifest` or something like that, which seems more fail-fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a slightly simpler example:

```
def getManifest[A: Manifest] = implicitly[Manifest[A]]
```

Or the equivalent desugared version:

```
def getManifest[A](implicit whatever: Manifest[A]) = whatever
```

And then:

```
scala> def getIt[T]: Manifest[T] = getManifest
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Manifest[Nothing]
 required: Manifest[T]
Note: Nothing <: T, but trait Manifest is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: T`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       def getIt[T]: Manifest[T] = getManifest
                                   ^
```

What's happening is that when the compiler tries to infer the type parameter for `getManifest`, there are lots of types that have `Manifest` instances in scope, and it has no way to choose between them, so it goes with its default choice, `Nothing`.

(You're seeing this error at runtime instead of compile-time because, well, that's what happens when you use reflection-based approaches to serialization.)

We can add a context bound:

```
def getIt[T: Manifest]: Manifest[T] = getManifest
```

Or, equivalently:

```
def getIt[T](implicit whatever: Manifest[T]): Manifest[T] = getManifest
```

Now everything is fine—there's a single most precise `Manifest` instance in scope, so the compiler can (appropriately) resolve the type parameter for `getManifest` to `T`.

You can see this a little more dramatically in the following example:

```
scala> trait Foo[A]
defined trait Foo

scala> def getFoo[A: Foo] = implicitly[Foo[A]]
getFoo: [A](implicit evidence$1: Foo[A])Foo[A]

scala> implicit object stringFoo extends Foo[String]
defined module stringFoo

scala> def getIt[T]: Foo[T] = getFoo
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo[String]
 required: Foo[T]
       def getIt[T]: Foo[T] = getFoo
                              ^
```

Since there's only one `Foo` instance in scope (for `String`), the compiler can pick it when it's resolving the type parameter for `getFoo`, and we end up with a different type mismatch.